# Is there an easy way to notify other fields whenever a @property field was modified

Tags: python, class, class-design, color-conversion

I'm trying to define a class integrated with multi-kinds of expression of color space.

i.e.,

```
#'hsv', 'rgb'...such fields are different color space expression of one thing.

my_color = MyColor('#ffffff')
my_color.rgb   #(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
my_color.rgb24 #(255, 255, 255)
my_color.hsv   #(0.0. 0.0, 1.0)
```

And for some purpose, I hope this class can support some basic mathematical operation,

```
my_color.hsv[2] -= 1.0
```

Of course, all fields should sync their value when any other 'bonded' field was modified.

```
#after operation above.
my_color.rgb   #(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
my_color.rgb24 #(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
my_color.hsv   #(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

What's the best way of doing so.

I've tried the @property and @setter annotation.

```
@property
def hsv(self):
    return self._hsv

@hsv.setter
def hsv(self, val):
    self._hsv = val
    _sync_change()  #update other fields by the new hsv value
```

I hope the @setter could help me updates other fields based on the new 'hsv' value. When I do the assignment operation to my_color.hsv, it does work.

```
my_color.hsv = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
print(my_color.rgb, my_color.rgb24) #shows correct value.
```

However, when I take a modification, not on the tuple but on an element of the tuple, things get wrong.

```
my_color.hsv[2] -= 1.0
print(my_color.rgb, my_color.rgb24) #nothing changed.
print(my_color.hsv)  #nothing changed.
```

I wonder what happens when I got that wrong, and what can I do with the @setter way, or is there a better and natural way for doing so.

Comment: `my_color.hsv[2] -= 1.0` isn't going to sync without really nasty, not-worth-it, breeding-ground-for-bugs custom sequence types.

Answer (score 0):

Your property returns a list object, and that list object is essentially separate. As far as the property is concerned, you only *read* that list object.

Your augmented assignment statement:

```
my_color.hsv[2] -= 1.0
```

otherwise doesn't *set* that property. It sets an index inside the list. The following is roughly equivalent:

```
_hsv_list = my_color.hsv
_hsv_list[2] = _hsv_list[2].__isub__(1.0)  # __isub__ is called to handle -=
```

There is no `my_color.hsv = _hsv_list` there, so your setter is never called.

So the trick would be to return a custom object, one that lets you intercept `__setitem__` and other accesses:

```
from collections.abc import Sequence

class HSVValues(Sequence):
    _parent: MyColor

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self._parent = parent

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._parent._hsv)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self._parent._hsv[item]

    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        self._parent._hsv[item] = value
        self._parent._sync_change()
```

and return that from your property:

```
@property
def hsv(self):
    return HSVValues(self)
```

So now `my_color.hsv` returns not the `_hsv` value, but an instance of the above class.

With that object replacing the original list, the `_hsv_list[2] = _hsv_list[2].__isub__(1.0)` will call `__setitem__`, which then first updates  `self._parent._hsv[2]`, then calls the `_sync_change()` method on the parent class to have it work out all the other values.

You probably want to have `_sync_changes` accept some more information about what changed; if it knows that `_hsv[2]` changed that could make syncing operations more efficient.

Comment: "Your property returns a list object" - well, probably, anyway. They claim it's a tuple, and they assigned a tuple, but `my_color.hsv[2] -= 1.0` would have raised a `TypeError` if it was a tuple, so something isn't right. Maybe something happened in `_sync_change`, or maybe it's something else the questioner didn't show us.

Comment: @user2357112: it all looks to me like they abstracted a little too much, because `_sync_change()` has no reference to the calling instance either.

Comment: Yeah, that code doesn't make sense. (Also, your `__getitem__` is returning the whole `_hsv` object instead of just an element, and your `self._parent._sync_change` doesn't let the parent know which representation to sync changes from - a flaw also present in the code as posted in the question.)

Comment: @user2357112: thanks, I corrected my `__getitem__` mistake. Yes, I didn't touch upon `_sync_change` and the advantages of passing on more detail.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I just wrote those code by memories. It should be  `self._sync_change()` and `_hsv` was a list. I actually maintained a `_BASE_RGB_VAL` field for each instance. My expectation is, whenever other fields(no matter the list itself or the elements) was modified, this modification would be perceived by the instance, and convert the new value of whatever (`'_hsv', '_lab'`, ...) expression to RGB expression, then `self._sync_change()`  firstly update the RGB value to the maintained `_BASE_RGB_VAL`, then updates all other fields according to it.

Comment: If I use the custom object to handle the element-wise modification, does that means  I have to write multiple class respects to different kinds of color expressions because I must touch the respective field in parents' class.

Comment: @Abitalo: you could write a single class that handles all the fields; just give it extra parameters when returning it from a property. You could give it the `_hsv` list directly, and that it should call `_sync_changes()` with the argument `'hsv'`, or similar techniques that make the class reusable between different properties that all return a list-like object.